# How to get the category ID from the Magento 2 Admin Panel

Tags: magento-2.1

Need help to get the Category ID in Magento 2 through the Admin Panel.
- is there a way to get it through URL?
- through inspect the markup of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here's how go to the admin products>categories and click your desired category you want to open. and look into the url of the category there you can find the category ID. I hope this helps you.
There are lots of ways to determine the category ID's but this one is what I can offer you.

Comment: if you have any other way do let me know

Comment: That's the best easy way for you to determine  the category ID of your category. I use that method all the time. :)

Comment: I have used the following code to display specific category products in the page.

In the category_id=4011 I have 100 products.

{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4011" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
It's not displaying products. -Do I need to clear cache or not do let me know. @mazestricks

Comment: Please do reindex your site and clear you cache that might work. because if you change something specifically adding products or categories you need to reindex and clear the cache.  Did you add something to the site?

Comment: no I have not added added  I have added the block code in the respective page where I want to display.

Comment: Hmm strange so the problem is with your code. can you fully post your code in here? Thanks

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4011" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63905/discussion-between-ben-and-mazestricks).